# configure_file list of files -> #includes cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

This seems like something that should be easy to do, but I cant for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Basically, I want to take a source lists (for now, just a variable ${HDR_LIST}), and write them ALL as includes in a file. so if `HDR_LIST="foo.h;bar.h;baz.h;quz.h"` it would make the file

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
#include "baz.h"
#include "quz.h"
```

I'd like this file to only update if HDR_LIST changes.

The only way I can think to do it is to make a configure_file command...but this macro may be in a ton of places. Each each project sets the variable, I'm not sure how safe that is. I feel like there should be a better way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(MyTest)

set(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT
  "#include \"inc1.h\"")
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT
  "${CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT}\n#include \"inc2.h\"")
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT
  "${CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT}\n#include \"inc3.h\"")
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT
  "${CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT}\n#include \"inc4.h\"")

configure_file("${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeConfigurableFile.in"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myfile.h"
  @ONLY
)
unset(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT)
```

configure_file has a built-in write-only-if-different.

Comment: I was thinking of using configure file. However, I'm writing this function to be used in a bunch of projects. Is there any risk if CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT is set in a bunch of different directories?

Comment: You can unset it. I've just extended my example to do that.

Comment: Great feature thanks for pointing out. Does it make sense to use `@ONLY` here?

Comment: What is `CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT`? It doesn't seem documented anywhere

Comment: @MaëlNison it's just a custom variable here to hold the content of that custom file, which @steveire named `CMakeConfigurableFile.in`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for some combination of `foreach()` and `file(APPEND ...)`:

```
file(REMOVE "includes.h")
foreach(filename ${HDR_LIST})
    file(APPEND "includes.h" "#include \"${filename}\"")
endforeach(filename)
```

Whenever `HDR_LIST` is changed, CMake will be run again and the file will be regenerated.

---

If you want to write the file only if different, it is a bit hard, because AFAIK, there are not dependencies on variables in CMake. But you could do e.g. this workaround with some hashing:

```
set(new_includes "")
foreach(filename ${HDR_LIST})
    set(new_includes "${new_includes}#include \"${filename}\"")
    if(WIN32)
        set(new_includes "${new_includes}\r\n")
    else()
        set(new_includes "${new_includes}\n")
    endif()
endforeach()
string(SHA256 new_includes_hash "${new_includes}")

file(SHA256 "includes.h" current_includes_hash)
if(NOT current_includes_hash STREQUAL new_includes_hash)
    file(WRITE "includes.h" "${new_includes}")
endif()
```

Comment: Yes and no. If I did what you have there, it would be run on every build. The header C file would be touched (and thus, rebuilt) on every build, which is...annoying.

Comment: Well only if CMake is run again, which happens only when CMake detects you have modified some CMakeLists.txt or changed the variables. You want to avoid it even in those cases?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably not possible. But I added another possible solution to the answer - detect the changes explicitly using a hash.